# What does soundbite mean?

Tags: meaning

Hi everyone here is the context

Arguably, new media is, accordingly, facilitating a soundbite-level of knowledge for a soundbite news culture. Certainly such themes often came out in the interviews.

Comment: [***sound bite***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sound-bite)

Answer (score 2):

A soundbite is a short (probably no more than 20 to 30 seconds) excerpt of a longer speech that summarizes the point being made generally in a pithy or memorable fashion.  When a politician's speech is covered in the nightly news, it will generally be accompanied by one or two soundbites.

The sentence you quote is criticizing the fact that soundbites by their nature make it easy to make shallow arguments and impossible to make nuanced arguments.  Political battles waged with competing soundbites generally do not involve seriously considering the arguments of the opposition or the complexities of reality.